# How to run two separate django instances on same server/domain?

Tags: django

To elaborate, we have one server we have setup to run django. Issue is that we need to establish "public" test server that our end-users can test, before we push the changes to the production.

Now, normally we would have `production.domain.com` and `testing.domain.com` and run them separately. However, due to conditions outside our control we only have access to one domain. We will call it `program.domain.com` for now.

Is there a way to setup two entirely separete django intances (AKA we do not want admin of production version to be able to access demo data, and vice versa) in such a way we have `program.domain.com/production` and `program.domain.com/development` enviroments?

I tried to look over [Djangos "sites"-framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/sites/#module-django.contrib.sites) but as far as I can see, all it can do is separate the domains, not paths, and it has both "sites" able to access same data.

However, as I stated, we want to keep our testing data and our production data separate. Yet, we want to give our end-user testers access to version they can tinker around, keeping separation of production, public test and local development(runserver command) versions.

Comment: You can run two independent Django processes on different ports, then have a reverse-proxy web server in front of that which listens to the usual port 80/443 and proxies requests to one or the other Django instance/port depending on the requested path.

Comment: this is a better approach actually.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you use the `/production` or `/development` path to select which database to use. You can read more about multitenancy from here https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-multi-tenant/en/latest/

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend a single Django instance to switch this internally if it’s for separating testing and production environment, as you’ll usually want to have different versions of the code running in those two environments.

Comment: @deceze voiced my concern with this approach. Our development/testing version will be running "hot" code, stuff we need to test and which might break. Our production version should only contain stable code base.